# Using Apple Configurator 2, do I need to be enrolled in the 'device enrollment program' to supervise my device?

Tags: ios, apple-id

When I try to prepare a device in Apple Configurator 2 (manual setup, supervise devices, Do not enroll in MDM ), I am asked to sign in to the Device Enrollment Program, and since I'm not part of it I get an error when I sign in with my apple id:

"*email* cannot access the Device Enrollment Program. Please contact your organization’s administrators."

I have supervised devices before with an older version of Apple Configurator, is this a recent requirement?

Is it no longer possible to manually supervise a device without enrolling en the 'Device enrollment Program'?

Comment: This sounds like a question for Apple management

Answer (score 11):

I know this response is several months later, but in case anyone else is looking for the answer...

When you get to the sign-in to DEP screen, just hit next without filling anything out.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I was so sure that the 'Next' button wouldn't work that I wouldn't even have tried to click it without this suggestion.

Comment: OH MY GOD. Thank you for this answer. I cannot belive this :D.

Comment: WHY is this designed like this?! THANK YOU. Is a **"Skip"** button so difficult?!